# Can you change Bitnami's Kafka host to localhost?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, bitnami

In my k8s cluster I ran the commands:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

helm install kafka bitnami/kafka -n <my-namespace>
```

And I think this is supposed to give me access to the broker through the:

Host - `kafka.<my-namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Port - 9092

What I wanna know is how do I change the host from that to just "localhost" and if I'm thinking correctly. I only need access inside the cluster. I'm pretty sure this should all be very obvious, but I don't see a straight forward way of doing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the Kafka service name. If you want to access Kafka via `localhost` (or outside of Kubernetes network, from your host), then you should use `kubectl port-forward`, or define a Ingress or ClusterIP/NodePort to do something similar. Otherwise, containers within the cluster refer to themselves as localhost, so wouldn't be able to reach Kafka that way unless in the same pod, which is not recommended deployment pattern for a Kafka cluster.

I'd also recommend using an operator rather than simply Helm.

Related - https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/